# Repaint CSS before JavaScript runs (to show progress indicator)

Tags: javascript, css, graphics, repaint

I have a JS routine (triggered by the user) that can take some time to complete. While the routine is running, I want to show a progress overlay on screen. Here's the code that calls the routine (this is called in response to a click event):

```
function handleClick() {
    $('div#progressOverlay').removeClass('hidden');
    myBigRoutine();
    ...
    $('div#progressOverlay').addClass('hidden');
}
```

The class toggle triggers a change in `opacity` and `visibility` (animated with a transition).

The class changes themselves are working fine; the first is executed before the slow routine and the second is executed after everything else.

**The issue is that the visual appearance of `#progressOverlay` doesn't change until after `myBigRoutine()` finishes.**
The result is that the progress overlay flashes on screen for a split second and then is immediately hidden again (all with no animation)

Is there a way to force the visual update/repaint to occur before (or, even better, in parallel with) the big JavaScript routine?

Comment: why not use web workers? They are meant for stuff like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind an event to animation finish. So, when animation finishes, only then your code will execute,

```
function handleClick() {
    $('div#progressOverlay').removeClass('hidden');

}

$("div#progressOverlay").bind("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function(){
    myBigRoutine();
    ...
    $('div#progressOverlay').addClass('hidden');
});
```

I hope, this is what you need :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `myBigRoutine()` function should be called asynchronously.

```
function handleClick() {
  $('div#progressOverlay').removeClass('hidden');
  setTimeout(function() {
    myBigRoutine();
    ...
    $('div#progressOverlay').addClass('hidden');
  }, 150);
}
```

150 is a magic number that means timeout delay in milliseconds. It can be any small number.

Also, consider using `.hide()` and `.show()` jQuery methods instead of `hidden` class.

Comment: This technique works, but I have to use at least 150ms for the delay. What worries me is that the repaint will take longer on slower systems, so I would have to either use a very long delay and slow things down or use a short delay and not have it be long enough for everyone's system. It would be great if there was a way to programmatically either queue the repaint before the routine or detect when the repaint has finished.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. But I doubt there will be this issue on slow systems. 10 ms apparently is too small for browser to start repainting a page. But once repaint is started, it will not be interrupted by firing timeout event. Timeout callback will be called after repaint is finished.

Comment: The issue here is the CSS transition, which animates the opacity of the overlay. If the delay is too short, it is interrupted and gets stuck at whatever stage in the animation has been reached, meaning that too short of a delay could cause the overlay to be only half visible.